# When I click CTRL+ALT+M i get pop up window macrium reflect

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, ctrl

Thats what is happening on my new laptop, but on my PC because I'm working on some application and I coded ctrl alt m to get Menu window, and thats working but on my new laptop i get something like macrium reflect, i guess i have to set up keyboard, can someone help me?

i dont know what to try

Comment: You have to configure macrium reflect to disable its hotkey so you can use it in your program.

Comment: @RaymondChen I just uninstalled macrium reflect, now it works